# Dynamic daemon process starting/stopping in PHP

Tags: php, twitter, streaming, daemon, worker

I'd like to start a daemon process on a user action (when they login, their Twitter timeline is being streamed), but I have no idea where to start. I understand how to create a single daemon worker to manually start and run in the background, but how should I do it dynamically? I want to have a lot of process running in the background asynchronously.

Could you give me some point where to start, or how to look for it? Because I couldn't really find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could handle it with ReactPHP and its child-process component.